# beautifulsoup is not extracting a text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape 8415219212510 from the following html

```
<td headers="th1" style="width: 125px;" valign="top">
  <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RFQNsn.aspx?value=8415219212510&amp;category=issue&amp;Scope=" title="go to NSN view">8415-21-921-2510</a>
</td>
```

I used

```
main_page = 'https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RfqRecs.aspx?category=issue&TypeSrch=dt&Value=09-14-2017'

dibbssoup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.content, 'html5lib')
#grabs each rfq
containers1 = dibbssoup.find_all("tr", {"class": "BgWhite"})            
NSN = container1.find("td", {"headers": "th1"}).a.get_text(strip=True)
```

and

```
NSN = container1.find("td", {"headers": "th1"}).a.text
```

Still I get this error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What's the actual site URL from the `BeautifulSoup` object?  Is `container1` a `Tag`?

Comment: You've used `containers1` then `container1`.

Comment: Can't access your link either.  And `main_page` is a string.  It doesn't have an attribute `.content`.  You need to make a request from that url first.  Your code has enough typos that its tough to tell whether the typos are the culprit of your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, BeautifulSoup doesn't handle any HTTP interactions, you need to feed it a downloaded HTML document. To do so, you can use a library like `requests`. I can't access the link you provided but I hope you get the right idea.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
NSN = soup.select_one('a[title*=NSN]').get_text()
```